# WPF Adorner Layer & Modal Window Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, modal-dialog, adorner

I have created a WPF application so that when a Modal dialog opens it is centered in the middle of the screen and there is an overlay (adorner layer) over the parent window. This all works perfectly however if I switch to a different Windows User and then log back in... the overlay is gone and the modal window is no longer centered vertically instead it is at the top of the window.

I cannot for the life of me workout why this is happening... anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You will have to attach the parent property of your modal window to the parentwindow. this will make the modal window stay on the screen.

Comment: I've already set the ModalWindow.Owner property. 

The modal window is staying on the screen. The issue is the position is changing but it's only changing when switching user on windows.

Comment: Follow this blog this will help you in setting your window in center location.
http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/11/how-to-reposition-wpf-modal-window-at.html

Comment: I am already centering the modal window... the issue is when you re-login to an existing windows session. Unfortunately that article doesn't help one bit.

Comment: Can't you implement this logic on your window activated or window loaded event. so this way whenever your window session comes back you can reset your modal window to center.

Comment: It worked by firing that code on the Activated event. Cheers!